# XmlReader returning null on all occasions

Tags: java, xml-parsing, activemq-classic, xmlreader

i have a code which is to get dat from active mq and display the data on Rss feed, but the code give me no data on the feed, i get an empty list and the reason seems to be that XmlReader reader= null; i have set this line an dthe reder seems to be null during the whole execution.

```
public List<RssFeedMessage> readRssFeeds(@PathVariable String sourceName) {
    XmlReader reader = null;
    RssFeedMessage rssFeedMessage = null;
    StringBuffer feedUrl = new StringBuffer("http://").append(ipaddress).append(":")
            .append(port).append("/admin/queueBrowse/").append(sourceName).append("?view=rss&feedType=rss_2.0");
    List<RssFeedMessage> rssFeedMessages = new ArrayList<RssFeedMessage>();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(feedUrl.toString());
        reader = new XmlReader(url);
        SyndFeed feedMsg = new SyndFeedInput().build(reader);
        List<SyndEntry> feedEntries = feedMsg.getEntries();
        for (SyndEntry entry : feedEntries) {
            rssFeedMessage = new RssFeedMessage();
            rssFeedMessage.setTitle(entry.getTitle());
            rssFeedMessage.setDescription(entry.getDescription().getValue());
            rssFeedMessage.setDate(OptimerUtil.simpleDateHourTimeInd.format(entry.getPublishedDate()));

            rssFeedMessages.add(rssFeedMessage);
        }
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FeedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    return rssFeedMessages;
}
}
```

it just exits coz reader remains null the wole time an i get io exception on reader = new XmlReader(url);

[image]

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace. If you open a browser and paste the built url in as an address does it work?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon it shows me a bunch of crap which i dont even need

Answer (score 0):

Check what `feedUrl` contains in line `URL url = new URL(feedUrl.toString());`

There is probably a problem with the string.
Also, make you you manage conditions like String equals `null` or unreachable, before parsing it

Comment: it contains  http://localhost:61616/admin/queueBrowse/SMSC_Logica?view=rss&feedType=rss_2.0, n wen i try it on the browser it gives me garbage and the XmlReader object reader is always null , it does not go into the list at all and jumps ahead to io exception and prints stacktrace